# How can I return chrome's scrollbar to default values after it is customized with ::-webkit-scrollbar?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

Some CSS that I inherit has code like this

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

I need to override this and return the scrollbar to default, but the following does not work.

```
my-element::-webkit-scrollbar {
  all: unset !important
}

my-element::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  all: unset !important;
}
```

How can I do it?

After you add any property to ::-webkit-scrollbar, chrome starts treating the scrollbar as custom, and never comes back to the default one. For example if I I have

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

and then I do

```
my-element::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: unset !important;
  background-color: unset !important;
}
```

and it won't go back to default, it will just disappear. `initial` has the same effect.

[This](https://codepen.io/Damian-Pereira/pen/xxMVXav) is a code pen with the example. How can I undo the customizations and get the real default chrome scrollbar back?